# validating input age with moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js to validate age is over 18 years old.

My code:

```
function validate(date){
var eighteenYearsAgo = moment().subtract("years", 18);
var birthday = moment(date);

if (!birthday.isValid()) {
    return "invalid date";    
}
else if (eighteenYearsAgo.isAfter(birthday)) {
    return "okay, you're good";    
}
else {
    return "sorry, no";    
}
```

}

I got a input

```
<input type="text" name"SocialSecurityNumber">
```

How can i attach this script to the input so it validates age, everytime somone leaves the input field? (blur)

Comment: `onblur = "return validate(this.value;"` ? Although selecting the input or form in advance and hooking on it using the standard `addEventListener` is likely a better approach.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminGruenbaum, could you please provide me with a working example would be very thankful!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="SocialSecurityNumber" onblur="return validate(this.value);" />
```

Personally, I use jquery validator and made this method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("minage", function(value,element,argument){
  var age = moment(value);
  var now = moment();
  return this.optional(element) || now.diff(age,'years') >= argument;
}, $.format("Applicant must be at least {0} years old."));
```